# Android Number Picker "shadows"

Tags: android, transparency, android-number-picker

The number pickers in Android contain a shadow above the previous and next value(s). Is there a attribute to make this shadow transparent?

[image: shadow above and below the 0s]

If an image is being used as the background, these shadows are distracting.

**Edit:**
Running emulator with Android version 6.0.

Setting the `solidColor` attribute makes the shadows appear in different colors. Unfortunately, setting it to transparent still keeps the black fading appearance.

How this renders during emulation with the background image:

[image]

Comment: Which android version are you using for development?

Comment: The emulator that I'm using is running 6.0.0 with API Level 23. The Min Sdk Version is set to 6.0 in the Flavors of the Project Structure.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just the Android version is too old. I didn't do any customization to numberpicker and it still looks flat (no ugly shadow like that). My test device running 6.0

Comment: What's the color of your background? My device is also running 6.0.

Comment: white, but I tested on blue as well. The "shadow" (more like an alpha mask) on mine is just to fade out the above and below number. The way your number picker appears seems very odd. It should look like this: https://www.android-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/number-picker.png